# How do computers interpret programming languages?

Tags: c, computer-science

I'm interested to know how programming languages are interpreted by machines. I was looking at some language comparison/benchmarks and noticed that some programming languages are written in the C programming language while others were written in others. For example Ruby and JVM (although not a language) are written in C. But why did the people who wrote Ruby or JVM write it in C? Couldn't they write it in a way like C, which , I guess, wasn't written in another language. :-) Was it just because not to reinvent the wheel or is C the god of machines?

Comment: Look into interpreted vs. compiled languages, and then compiling to bytecode vs. machine code.  Your question implies that you don't understand the differences between them.  You probably won't be able to formulate a question on the subject until you really get those differences.

Comment: @Timur You need to "Accept" the valid answers to your other questions. You might read the site's FAQ to learn a bit about what types of questions you should ask here, and how other aspects of the site work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to write them in something. They could be written directly in machine language (actual processor instructions) but that would be very cumbersome - and not portable. So another - preferably standard, portable and ubiquitous - language (like C) is a much better option.

Comment: so, every machine has its own code, and people who write languages have to know those machine codes in order to make their language convert itself into a machine code?

Comment: Every machine (= processor, and sometimes the operating system also makes a difference) has its own machine language. So if you write something in C and compile it for a PC or for a Mac you'll get a different output (and on a PC you'll get a different output if you compile it for Windows or for Linux). But once you have C on a platform and an interpreter - for any language - which is written in C you can execute scripts written in that language on the given platform. So if you write an interpreter for a language in C you don't need to write it in a machine-specific language.

Answer (score 0):

C (and C++, FORTRAN, etc) is compiled directly to machine code, while Ruby and Java are compiled to bytecode which is interpreted by a virtual machine, which is like a software platform on top of the hardware.